# Matrix multiplication - loose definition of non-conformable matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose we have the following:

```
x <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
y <- c(1,2,3)
x%*%y
y%*%x
```

Why are the matrix multiplications not undefined? We know that `x` is a 3 x 3 matrix and `y` is a 1 x 3 matrix. So `x %*% y` should not be defined and `y %*% x` should be a 1 x 3 matrix.

Comment: The answer is found in the first section of `help("%*%")` output.

Answer (score 7):

Luckily (or unfortunately, depending on the situation) many R operators (in their default state) are overloaded and do all sorts of things 'under the hood' - in this example, the default functionality for `%*%` in `R` automatically coerces `y` to matrix whose dimension will work. When you type

```
x %*% y
```

it makes `y` a 3 x 1 matrix and when you type

```
y %*% x
```

it makes `y` a 1 x 3 matrix.

Try comparing those with when you type

```
x %*% as.matrix(y)
```

and

```
t(as.matrix(y)) %*% x
```

respectively

Comment: I vote for "unfortunately". My experience has been that *implicit* coercion in R often causes obscure, hard to detect, and hard to debug behavior, whereas the *explicit* coercion facilities are maddening in their ability to do the "wrong" thing! :-) Despite its many and varied flaws, on balance, I still like R and use it regularly.

Comment: +1 for "unfortuntately". There are already lots of stats packages out there that try to do the thinking for the user...

Comment: If you are still in a whinging frame of mind, then you should also be mentioning what happens when you extract a single column: `(x%*%y)[,1]`

Comment: @DWin, I'm not sure what you're driving at. Once you do the multiplication, e.g. `x%*%y`, a new matrix is created based on however it had to coerce to do make the multiplication work and then you're just indexing that matrix as usual. So, `x%*%y` multiplies a (3 x 3) by a (3 x 1) to get a (3 x 1) and so extracting the first column just gives a vector of length 3 and with `y%*%x` you have a (1 x 3) so the first column is just a scalar. I've probably missed your point...

Comment: What it all comes down to (my personal inference) is that R is primarily a data analysis tool so matrix operations are designed to DWIM, where "I" is a statistician.  Alternatively,  Matlab's DWIM is aimed at "I" being a linear algebraist.

Comment: It strikes me that it's more accurate to say "the current way the code for the `%*%` operator is written coerces..."  than to blame this coercion on the fundamental R engine.  One could easily write his own operator which did not do such a coercion.

Comment: Ok @CarlWitthoft, I changed the language somewhat to eliminate that possible interpretation. Thanks.